# convert attachments in mail to pdf in lotus notes

Tags: pdf-generation

I want to conert the mail document and attachments to pdf,

If there’s any text in the mail body along with the attachment then the mail content should be converted to pdf in the first page of the pdf, followed by the attachment (in the next page/s).

I am able to convert the mail body and attachment into seperate pdf's but not able to club them, in mail body as first page of pdf and attachments as other.

Please help.